# How to remove the contents between 2 strings from a xml document

Tags: c#, xml

I need to remove all the contents between  and    including those 2 as well .

I have tried using this

```
newLines = RemoveLines(newLines, "<!-- ENHANCED -->", "<!-- /ENHANCED -->", true);

    private static List<string> RemoveLines(List<string> newLines, string startingLine, string endingLine, bool removeContents)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < newLines.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (newLines[i].Trim() != startingLine.Trim()) continue;

            newLines.RemoveAt(i);

            if (removeContents)
                for (var j = i; newLines[j].Trim() != endingLine.Trim(); j++)
                {
                    newLines.RemoveAt(j);
                    j--;
                }

            newLines.RemoveAt(i);

        }

        return newLines;
    }
```

but this doesnt work whe both strings appear on same line .

I have tried using xdocument as well .

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(file, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
    var nodes = xdoc.DescendantNodes();
    var newNodes = RemoveNodes(nodes, "<!-- ENHANCED -->", "<!-- /ENHANCED -->", true);

    var doc = new XDocument(newNodes);
    doc.Save(file);

private static IEnumerable<XNode> RemoveNodes(IEnumerable<XNode> nodes, string startingNode, string endingNode, bool removeBetweenNodes)
{
    var xNodes = nodes as IList<XNode> ?? nodes.ToList();
    for (var i = 0; i < xNodes.Count(); i++)
    {

        if (xNodes[i].ToString().Trim() != startingNode.Trim()) continue;

        xNodes.RemoveAt(i);

        if (removeBetweenNodes)
            for (var j = i; xNodes[j].ToString().Trim() != endingNode.Trim(); j++)
            {
                xNodes.RemoveAt(j);
                j--;
            }

        xNodes.RemoveAt(i);

    }

    return (IEnumerable<XNode>) xNodes;
}
```

This fails because of some referenced .dtd files missing in the folder .

Can this be done with reading to stream and then applyn regex . I am not good at regex . Can someone help ?

Comment: Do you have a sample for that file?

Comment: Care to add it in your question?

Comment: Had similar issue last week.  Solution was to make a list of nodes that needed to be removed and then remove than from last node to first node.  Like any list item when you remove an item it effects all the items below the current item.  So you have to remove the items from last to first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
//var content = @"
//    header 
//        <!-- ENHANCED --> details <!-- /ENHANCED --> 
//    trailler
//
//    |
//
//    first 
//        <!-- ENHANCED --> 
//            second 
//        <!-- /ENHANCED --> 
//    third";
var content = File.ReadAllText("file.xml");
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(content,
    @"<!-- ENHANCED -->[\s\S]*?<!-- /ENHANCED -->", ""));
```

In an XML file, the sequence `<!-- ... -->` defines a comment.

To avoid a hard time trying to match them with XPath, this regular expression will strip anything between both sequences, by treating that XML file as plain text.

You'll need to make sure that replaces doesn't break your XML document.